# Angular Package simple-pdf-viewer 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' CORS Issue While Using Laravel As Backend

Tags: angular, laravel, pdf, cors

I am developing angular application that needs to display a PDF on a web page.To achieve this i am using package **simple-pdf-viewer**.
This package works fine when i give path of my local PDF file like [local-path](http://localhost:4200/assets/example/pdf-test.pdf.)

,But when i give path of my live server like [live-path](https://booksapi.alphawods.com/storage/app/pdf-test.pdf) then It gives me error

> localhost/:1 Failed to load https://booksapi.alphawods.com/storage/app/pdf-test.pdf: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

I am using **Laravel** as back-end and **Angular** is at front-end. Normally this is a common CORS issue of Laravel which i have already configured and all my requests to server are working fine.

Here is the working CORS file screenshot that is being used on my server.   [cors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVWqL.png)

Here is the **simple-pdf-viewer** code that is calling the pdf resource

```
public openUrl(url: string, startAt: SimplePDFBookmark = SimplePDFBookmark.EMPTY_BOOKMARK) {debugger
  this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer',withCredentials: false })
  .subscribe((file: ArrayBuffer) => {
    this.openDocument(new Uint8Array(file), startAt);
  }, error => {
    this.onError.emit(error);
    this.loaded = false;
  });}
```

I have already read an issue related to this on GitHub, but could not find a solution.Here is the link of that issue [related-issue](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/issues/161)

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that you need to configure is your web server (`nginx`/`apache`) to allow the `CORS`. Adding `CORS` configuration on `Laravel` middleware will only works if the request hits your `Laravel` app. Since you are accessing file directly, the additional headers will never added because it's not hit any `Laravel` routes, right? So the request will just handled by the web server.

I hope this gives you some hints.